# Runtime-Error 424 Dictionary Object Not Found

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, runtime-error, runtime

I'm trying to loop through a data set, adding keys to a dictionary in order to determine if their are duplicate entries. However, when trying to test whether the key exists in the dictionary I am getting a runtime error 424

I've attempted to change from early to late binding, I've introduced the 'Triton' variable to the current module. And I've ensured all variables are declared.

```
Sub DupeCheckRec()

Dim TritonData As Variant
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim tempArr()
Dim i As Long
Dim KeyVal As String

    TritonData = Triton.Sheets(1).UsedRange

    For i = 2 To UBound(TritonData, 1)

        KeyVal = TritonData(i, 2) & TritonData(i, 3) & TritonData(i, 5) & TritonData(i, 6) & TritonData(i, 7) & TritonData(i, 10) & TritonData(i, 20)

        If dict(KeyVal).Exists = True Then

            tempArr(i, 1) = TritonData(i, 2)
            tempArr(i, 2) = TritonData(i, 3)
            tempArr(i, 3) = TritonData(i, 5)
            tempArr(i, 4) = TritonData(i, 7)
        Else
            dict.Add Key, i
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Result expected is any dupes get added to tempArr

Comment: What is `Key` ?

Comment: `dict.Exists(KeyVal)`.

Comment: ^^^That as well...

Comment: That was an amendment I made, Key should be KeyVal there

Comment: Also, 'Triton" is a public variable, I open the file up in another sub and use another sub to call both procedures

Comment: I think you missed BigBen's point.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you